# Pandas date_range from DatetimeIndex to Date format

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas `date_range` returns a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` which has the indexes formatted as a timestamps (date plus time). For example:

```
In  [114] rng=pandas.date_range('1/1/2013','1/31/2013',freq='D')
In  [115] rng
Out [116]
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-31 00:00:00]
Length: 31, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

Given I am not using timestamps in my application, I would like to convert this index to a date such that:

```
In  [117] rng[0]
Out [118]
<Timestamp: 2013-01-02 00:00:00>
```

Will be in the form `2013-01-02`.

I am using pandas version 0.9.1

Comment: There is no ``Datestamp`` analogue to ``Timestamp`` objects. If you are doing further analysis in pandas, you're best keeping these dates at ``Timestamp``s and just ignoring the zeros. If you want to extract them for output or display, @unutbu's solution below the way to go.

Comment: yes, why aren't you using Timestamps?

Comment: I am printing results to a spreadsheet which is then used as the input to an Access DB. The Access DB is flaking out because of the zeros.

Comment: you could use [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range), however I'm not sure about the format in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[to_pydatetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html?highlight=to_pydatetime#converting-to-python-datetimes) returns a NumPy array of Python `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
In [8]: dates = rng.to_pydatetime()

In [9]: print(dates[0])
2013-01-01 00:00:00

In [10]: print(dates[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
2013-01-01
```

Comment: Note you can apply strftime directly from a Timestamp object e.g. `rng.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`.

Answer (score 18):

For me the current answer is not satisfactory because internally it is still stored as a timestamp with hours, minutes, seconds.

Pandas version : 0.22.0

My solution has been to convert it to `datetime.date`:

```py
In[30]: import pandas as pd
In[31]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2013','1/31/2013', freq='D')
In[32]: date_rng = rng.date   # Here it becomes date
In[33]: date_rng[0]
Out[33]: datetime.date(2013, 1, 1)
In[34]: print(date_rng[0])
2013-01-01
```

Comment: Link to docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.date