# Filter pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df consisting of the columns expiration date, strike, call/put, bid and ask. Index is datetime. I want to filter for rows with ask=0 and bid=0, those rows are contained in dataframe df4. I want to check if there are other rows in that dataframe, which do contain the same values for expiration date and call/put, same datetime index entry, bid and ask different from zero and a strike with a defined stepwith above and below the strike of the column that has bid=ask=zero. If yes, there should be done some operations (interpolating between the bid and asks with regard to the strike ).

I came up with the following code, but it raises KeyError: 'the label [xy] is not in the [index]', obviously due to some datetime formating issue. The script iterates through the dataframe rows.

Here is my questions:
a) How should it be coded to work correctly?
b) Is there a way to fully vectorize this, since my real world data sample is rather large, around 2 GB?

Here is the code, I hope it explains at least, what I'm trying to do:

```
# constructing a sample dataframe
import pandas
import numpy.random as rd
dates = pandas.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pandas.DataFrame(rd.randn(8, 5), index=dates, columns=['call/put', 'expiration',  'strike', 'ask', 'bid'])
df.iloc[2,4]=0
df.iloc[2,3]=0
df.iloc[3,4]=0
df.iloc[3,3]=0
df.iloc[2,2]=0.5
df=df.append(df.iloc[2:3])
df.iloc[8:9,3:5]=1
df.iloc[8:9,2:3]=0.6
df=df.append(df.iloc[8:9])
df.iloc[9,2]=0.4

#filtering for rows with bid=ask=0
df4=df[(df["ask"]==0) & (df["bid"]==0)]

#checking for rows that can be used for bid and ask interpolation
stepsize=0.1
counter=0
for index, row in df4.iterrows():
 print index
 df_upperbound = df.loc[index]
 df_upperbound = df_upperbound[(df_upperbound['call/put']== df4['call/put']) &  (df_upperbound['expiration']== df4['expiration']) & (df_upperbound['strike']== df4['strike']+stepsize)]
 df_lowerbound = df.loc[index]
 df_lowerbound = df_lowerbound[ (df_lowerbound['call/put']== df4['call/put']) & (df_lowerbound['expiration']== df4['expiration']) & (df_lowerbound['strike']== df4['strike']-stepsize)]
 if len(df_upperbound)>0 and len(df_lowerbound)>0:
    is_upperbound = df_upperbound.ask!=0 and df_upperbound.bid!=0
    is_lowerbound = df_lowerbound.ask!=0 and df_lowerbound.bid!=0  
    if is_upperbound and is_lowerbound:
        counter+=1
```

Comment: post some example data that will allow people to run your code, and post the desired output for that subset of data.

Comment: The example dataframe called df is constructed below # constructing a sample dataframe. The whole given code snippet can be run via copy and paste. Within df there is two rows with bid = ask=0, for one of those rows both a row with a higher and a lower strike and ask=bid>0 can be found. Deired output in my codesnippet is counter=1. Instead of this I will perform an interpolation of bid and ask using the lower and higher strike thus replacing bid=ask=zero by some numbers.

Comment: right, but you should seed your random data and show expected output, otherwise the results will be different everytime.

Comment: Don't worry about the random numbers. Everything that has to be nonrandom is replaced in my snippet by something else. Whenever the code is run- 3rd and 4th row in df should be recocnized as bid=ask=zero and 3rd row should be recocnized as having rows that can be used for interpolation (last two rows in df), therefore setting counter to 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a workaround, but using strftime ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576615/pandas-date-range-from-datetimeindex-to-date-format)) seems to work ...

```
In[8] stepsize=0.1
      counter=0
      for index,row in df4.iterrows():
          print df[index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]


Out[9] call/put  expiration  strike  ask  bid
       2000-01-03  0.181998   -2.371192     0.5    0    0
       2000-01-03  0.181998   -2.371192     0.6    1    1
       2000-01-03  0.181998   -2.371192     0.4    1    1
           call/put  expiration    strike  ask  bid
       2000-01-04  0.030905    1.142885 -1.268263    0    0
```

Comment: Also works on my end. But why is a comparision of string and datetime working and a comparision of 2 identical datetime objects gives an error? Might this be a Pandas-bug?